# Javascript: Object in class instance, values being reassigned when called from variable

Tags: javascript, class, variables, javascript-objects

I'm building a bowling scorecard in JS and I'm having an issue with the way I store the scores for each individual bowl within a frame.

I'm doing so by passing the values into an instance of the frame class when it is created and storing those values in an object with the keys of firstBowl and secondBowl. The reason being, that I need to access the value of individual bowls from outside a frame in order to calculate strike and spare bonuses. (I also tried using an array and had the same issue as detailed below.)

The problem that I am having is that in my tests I am creating a strike frame that has a value of 10 for firstBowl and 0 for secondBowl and linking it to a variable I can call elsewhere in my tests. But when I call the strike, I find that both the firstBowl and secondBowl values have been set to 0 and that the total score is still 10. If I create a new strike frame within the test, it functions as I would expect.

Here is the code for my Frame class:

```
function Frame(firstBowl, secondBowl = 0){

  var bowls = new Object();
  bowls.firstBowl = firstBowl;
  bowls.secondBowl = secondBowl;

  this.score = 0;

  this.init = function(){
    if (bowls.firstBowl + bowls.secondBowl > 10) {
      throw new Error("Illegal Score: Can't be greater than 10")
    };
    this.score = bowls.firstBowl + bowls.secondBowl
  };

  this.init();

  Frame.prototype.getScore = function(){
    return this.score;
  };

  Frame.prototype.getStatus = function(){
    if(bowls.firstBowl === 10) {
      return "strike";
    }else if(bowls.firstBowl != 10 && this.getScore() === 10) {
      return "spare";
    }else if(this.getScore() === 0) {
      return "gutter";
    };
    return;
  };

  Frame.prototype.getBowls = function(){
    return bowls;
  };
};
```

and this is the failing test in question:

```
describe("Frames", function() {

  var frame;
  var strike;
  var spare;
  var gutter;

  beforeEach(function(){
    frame = new Frame(1, 1);
    strike = new Frame(10);
    spare = new Frame(5,5);
    gutter = new Frame(0,0);
  });

  it("Returns Frame Status as Strike when first bowl is 10", function(){
    expect(strike.getStatus()).toEqual("strike")
  });

});
```

And here is the console log for the frame when it it initialised in the beforeEach function compared to when it is called from within the test:

```
frameSpec.js:11 --Initialised-
frameSpec.js:12 Frame {score: 10, init: function}
frameSpec.js:13 Object {firstBowl: 10, secondBowl: 0}
frameSpec.js:14 strike
frameSpec.js:15 ------end-------


frameSpec.js:37 ---In Test--
frameSpec.js:38 Frame {score: 10, init: function}
frameSpec.js:39 Object {firstBowl: 0, secondBowl: 0}
frameSpec.js:40 spare
frameSpec.js:41 ------end-------
```

I've tried to google around and struggled to find anything (I've honestly found trying to phrase my question concisely a difficulty)

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I've just missed something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an unwanted closure in your code:

```
//simplified:
function Frame(first,second){
  Frame.prototype.getStatus=function(){//assigned to prototype => all instances
    return first+second;//these get bound whenever frame is called
  };
}
```

So what it does

```
var a=new Frame(0,0);
a.getStatus()//0
var b=new Frame(1,1);
b.getStatus();//2
a.getStatus();//2 == b.getStatus
```

So in fact getStatus always returns the value for the last element. Either make it a property of the local object:

```
this.getStatus=function(){}
```

or make it a static prototype and pass all values through the context:

```
function Frame(a,b){ this.a=a; this.b=b}
Frame.prototype.getStatus=function(){ return this.a+this.b};
```

---

Simplified code:

```
function Frame(one,two){
  if(one+two>10) throw new Error("wrong args");
  this.one=one;
  this.two=two||0;
  this.score=this.one+this.two;
  this.status=["gutter","strike"][this.score/10] || "regular";
  if(this.score==10 && this.one != 10) this.status=" spare";
}


console.log(new Frame(10));
```

http://jsbin.com/rohanihawo/1/edit

Comment: Thank you Jonas that's really clear and makes a lot of sense to me. Clearly I have a lot to learn about constructing classes in JS. Thanks again!